# Ionic change font color of disabled button

Tags: ionic3

How do I change the font color of an disabled button?

I have:

```
 <ion-col col-1><button class='buttoncell abc noactualbutton' ion-button [disabled]="true" [color]="white">{{row[8]}}</button></ion-col>
```

and SCSS:

```
   .noactualbutton[disabled]{
      color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
    }
```

But still, it is "whiter", but its still greyed out...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you disable button opacity is set 0.4 automatically. You can set your styling to button when it is disabled like below:

```
.noactualbutton:disabled, noactualbutton[disabled]{
      color: white;
      opacity: 1;
      background: #b3b3b3;
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

### Since Ionic v4 :

Using the `:disabled` CSS selector to target a disabled `ion-button` will not work as it only works on activable/focusable elements like a `button` or an `input`, instead, you have to use `[disabled]`.

Also, if you have set the `color` attribute of your `ion-button` (e.g. `<ion-button color="danger">My button</ion-button>` you can't change the background color using the `--background` CSS property, instead you have to use the `--ion-color-base` with `!important` (you don't have the choice since Ionic have defined their CSS property with it).

### Here is a full example :

```html
<ion-button color="danger" [disabled]="true">
  My button
</ion-button>
```

```css
ion-button[disabled] {
  --ion-color-base: #b34d5a !important;
}
```

Comment: Had to write `ion-button[disabled]:not([disabled='false'])` to get it right on `@ionic/react` v6

Answer (score 2):

```
ion-button {
    &[disabled] {
        opacity: 1;
        --background: #CCCCCC;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know of any documentation we can refer to for this styling?

Comment: @fineTuneFork https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button CSS Custom Properties